# The value of 'index' keeps to be 0 in 'onChange' while looping through material-ui rating component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to display the rating value of each products in my e-commerce react-js web app. I was able to track/handle which product has been hovered through it's index from JS map function. ('onChangeActive' is the handler for this)

```
 {products.map((product, index) => (
```

Although, "onChange" is always sending 0 for 'index' function parameter even if I click the stars of any product from the array list. As a result, I couldn't deliver the star feature

```
    <Rating
    name="hover-feedback"
    value={this.state.rateValue[index] === undefined ?
        product.rating_sum: this.state.rateValue[index]}
    precision={0.5}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => { // OnClick handler
        this.setValue(newValue, index);
    }}
    onChangeActive={(event, newValue) => { // onHover handler
        this.setHover(newValue, index);
    }}
/>
{this.state.rateHover[index] !== undefined && <Box ml={2}>
    {labels[this.state.rateHover[index] !== undefined ?
                                                              this.state.rateHover[index] : this.state.rateValue[index]]}</Box>}
```

setValue function

```
    setValue = (newValue, index) =>{

    console.log("value", index, newValue)

    if(newValue !== -1 && newValue!== null) {
        let oldValue = this.state.rateValue;
        oldValue[index] = newValue;

        this.setState({
                rateValue: oldValue,

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your code here as text, not an image. Include the part where index is defined.

Comment: I have posted where I declared the 'index' in the first part. Also, image has been replaced with code.

Comment: What does `setValue` do?

Comment: Both 'setValue' and 'setHover' update/set the value of hovered/clicked start value of each product. I kept those start value as an array which directly corresponds  with the products. Something like this:

product= [p0, p1, p2 .....]
rateValue = [p0, p1, 2 .....]
hoverValue = [p0, p1, p2 ....

Anyhow, I'm getting 0 for index during onChange

Answer (score 1):

You should use React `useState` and not try to reinvent the wheel with your custom state definition. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

```js
// Get a hook function
const {
  useState
} = React;

const Example = ({
  title
}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    rateValue: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  });

  const products = [{
      rating_sum: 4
    },
    {
      rating_sum: 6
    },
    {
      rating_sum: 5
    },
  ]

  const setValue = (event, index) => {

    const newValue = event.target.value

    console.log("value", index, newValue)

    if (newValue !== -1 && newValue !== null) {
      const {
        rateValue
      } = state
      setState({
        rateValue: [
          ...rateValue.slice(0, index), newValue, ...rateValue.slice(index + 1)
        ]
      })
    }
  }
  return ( <
    div > {
      products.map((product, index) => {
        return <div >
          <
          input value = {
            index
          }
        type = 'number'
        onChange = {
          (event, newValue) => {
            setValue(event, index)
          }
        }
        /> < /
        div >
      })
    } < div > {
      state.rateValue
    } < /div>< /
    div >
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  Example title = "Example using Hooks:" / > ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tho, the issue is before even handling the state. As you can see on in the 'setValue' method, I'm logging the result through console and the index value is always 0

Comment: What even is index? you never show the initialisation. My point stands; use built-in methods of dealing with state.

Comment: I have already posted the place where index is being initialized. 

{products.map((product, index) => (

It's JS map builtin mechanism to track the index of your array during loop.